# Collapse a list on the same columns across the elements R

Tags: r

I have the following elements in a list and I want to collapse them into a data frame where only the same columns across the list are retained.

I tried the following but it doesn't give me exactly what I want. Since it just NAs the columns that aren't in the other element. I would be even better to be able to choose which columns to collapse on.

```
n.obs <- sapply(lst, length)
seq.max <- seq_len(max(n.obs))
mat <- t(sapply(lst, "[", i = seq.max))




lst[[1]]
$id
[1] "akromils-production"

$name
[1] "Akro-Mils Production"

$month
[1] 12000

$year
[1] 137000

$units
[1] 3000

$clients
[1] 6

$pbox
[1] FALSE

$punits
[1] 0

$cbox
[1] FALSE

$cunits
[1] 0

$sbox
[1] FALSE

$sunits
[1] 0

$eval
[1] FALSE

$public
[1] FALSE

lst[[2]]
$id
[1] "adc-production-2"

$name
[1] "American Diagnostics - Production (2)"

$month
[1] 26000

$year
[1] 312000

$units
[1] 650

$clients
[1] 2

$pbox
[1] TRUE

$punits
[1] 650

$eval
[1] FALSE

$public
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: In order to make your question more reproducible could you please provide `lst`and `seq.max`? E.g. `dput(lst)`, and if `seq.max` is a function, which package?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you should *always* provide reproducible sample data and code. Minimal sample data is best provided with `dput`, which avoids us having to manually type out your data, and also avoids ambiguities due to unknown/ambiguous data types. You've been around SO for a while, so you should know how to post [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

In response to your question, one option would be to use `dplyr::bind_rows` and `dplyr::bind_cols` and then select only those columns that don't contain `any` `NA`s.

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(map(lst, bind_cols)) %>% select_if(~!any(is.na(.x)))
## A tibble: 2 x 10
#  id         name           month   year units clients pbox  punits eval  public
#  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>  <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 akromils-… Akro-Mils Pro… 12000 137000  3000       6 FALSE      0 FALSE FALSE
#2 adc-produ… American Diag… 26000 312000   650       2 TRUE     650 FALSE FALSE
```

---

### Sample data

```
lst <- list(
    list(
        id = "akromils-production",
        name = "Akro-Mils Production",
        month = 12000,
        year = 137000,
        units = 3000,
        clients = 6,
        pbox = FALSE,
        punits = 0,
        cbox = FALSE,
        cunits = 0,
        sbox = FALSE,
        sunits = 0,
        eval = FALSE,
        public = FALSE),
    list(
        id = "adc-production-2",
        name = "American Diagnostics - Production (2)",
        month = 26000,
        year = 312000,
        units = 650,
        clients = 2,
        pbox = TRUE,
        punits = 650,
        eval = FALSE,
        public = FALSE)
)
```